# Páginas dinâmicas através de request

Tags: php, html

Estou montando uma aplicação web de uma forma em que as manutenções futuras sejam bem simplificadas.

Assim, comecei a pesquisar por paginas dinâmicas, etc.
Só que na pratica, não sei nem como começar.

**Queria que ficasse assim:**

- header.php: cabeçalho com menu lateral linkando para outras paginas
- content.php: (ja tenho feito )
- footer.php: (Já tenho feito )

---

Na minha index.php, eu chamo os arquivos css, js, etc. E dou um include no header, content, footer...

Estruta das pastas :

1. lib/
2. application/
3. controllers/
4. template/ header.php , content.php,   footer.php

   - index.php

Até ai blz ...

No meu header, no menu, tem vários link, mas eu não queria ter que criar 15, 20 paginas diferentes. Mas sim, 1 unica pagina com o conteúdo referente a cada link.

Como faço isso?

---

Fiquei pensando em como poderia fazer isso , junto com o banco de dados , nos teste esta quase tudo se saindo bem , mas não esta exibindo meu conteudo.

Segue como eu fiz :

Criei uma tabela (tblPaginas) , nela coloqueui os campos : id ,name , controller , arg e ennable.

```
id name     controller arg  ennable
1  index                0     0

2  pagina1     pag      1     1

3  pagina2     pag      2     1

4  pagina3     pag      3     1
```

etc

No meu header , coloquei o seguinte :

```
<?php       
    echo '
        <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;">
                    <i class="icon-basket"></i>
                    <span class="title">PAGINAS</span>
                    <span class="arrow "></span>
            </a>';

    echo ' <ul class="sub-menu">';

                $sql= ("SELECT * FROM tblPaginas where ennable = 1 and arg > '0' order by id ");
                $query = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {

                echo'                         
                    <li>
                            <a href="index.php?'.$row['controller'].'='.$row['arg'].'">
                            <text style="TEXT-TRANSFORM: uppercase;">'.$row['name'].' </text></a>
                    </li>' ;}

                    echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</li>';
?>
```

Assim  , ele exibe meu menu lateral  , pegando o 'name' (nome da pagina no menu) , e enviando o controller e o arg pela URL .

Na minha pagina content.php  , tentei fazer o seguinte :

```
<?php
$uri = $_GET['arg'];

    $var = $uri;
    switch ($var)
{
    case 1:
    include 'pag/geral.php';
    break;

    case 2:
    include 'pag/pagina2.php';
    break;

    case 3:
    echo "DEU CERTO O 3";
    break;
}

?>
```

Mas, ele não esta exibindo as paginas , não esta funcionando este codigo que fiz da pagina content.

Pensei em fazer assim , pois posso mais tarde tentar fazer um painel de controle , e editar as paginas pelo banco.

Podem me ajudar a fazer este codigo funcionar?

Comment: Comece pesquisando sobre include!

Comment: Recomendo você a usar uma lib de templates, é muito fácil e ajuda muito nessa hora, dê uma olhada nesse site http://raelcunha.com/template.php.

Comment: Boa tarde Eduardo , Consegui resolver meu problema , criei mais 1 variavel para fazer o controle das paginas , e deu certo

Comment: @HenriqueFelix Poste como resposta a solução que fizeste nos comentários, dessa forma sua pergunta será devidamente respondida e ajudará a comunidade.